# MongoDB update value with the result of a query performed on another collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to update the field of a collection with a value picked in another collection. I use the value of the field which needs to be updated for finding the new value in the other collection.

I try this :

```
 db.Organizations.find({}).forEach( function(doc) {
    print(doc.Country.DisplayName);
    var c = db.Countries.find({"DisplayName": doc.Country.DisplayName});
    doc.Country = c;
    print(doc.Country.DisplayName);
});
```

The result:

```
Philippines 
[unknown type]
```

How can I achieve this ?
Thanks in advance.

Edit :
I found the solution with using `findOne()` (there's no duplicate country in my collection)

```
var index = 0;
db.Organizations.find({"Country": { $ne: null }}).forEach( function(doc) {
   print(index + ': ' + doc.Country.DisplayName);

  var myDoc = db.Countries.findOne({"DisplayName": doc.Country.DisplayName});
  if (myDoc){
        print(index + ': ' + myDoc);
        doc.Country = myDoc;
        print(index + ': ' + doc.Country.DisplayName);
   }

  index++;

});
```

And the result :

`0: Philippines
0: [object BSON]
0: Philippines
1: Singapore
1: [object BSON]
1: Singapore`

Comment: What you trying to do? **update** the documents in one collection?  Please show us sample documents for two collections and the expected result.

Comment: I want to update the field `Country` of the Organizations collection  with the result of a query performed on the Countries collection. The result must be `Philippines Philippines`

Comment: Can we see your documents?

Answer (score 1):

The second `find(...)` is also an async operation so you have to pass there a callback as well like so:

```
db.Organizations.find({}).forEach( function(doc) {
    print(doc.Country.DisplayName);
    db.Countries.find({"DisplayName": doc.Country.DisplayName}, function(err, cursor) {
        doc.Country = cursor.next();
        print(doc.Country.DisplayName);        
    });
});
```

Comment: It seems not working as I can note it with print `Philippines
Singapore
Hong Kong
Hong Kong
Singapore
Hong Kong
Hong Kong
Hong Kong
Hong Kong
Hong Kong
Hong Kong
Singapore
Singapore
Singapore
Pakistan
Singapore
Singapore
Hong Kong` but I have found a solution by using `findOne()`